# What is the difference between the interval $[-\infty, +\infty]$ and the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I wish to use the word "one point compactification" in a more precise way.

In the past, I tend to refer to  $[-\infty, +\infty]$ as the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}$.

However, I feel that this usage of terminology is not very precise.

Can I get an expert opinion as to the difference between the extended interval $[-\infty, +\infty]$ (which seems to be a very natural extension of $\mathbb{R}$) and the "one point compactification" of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: $[-\infty, +\infty]$ is more of a "two-point compactification", and looks like a line segment with its endpoints. The one-point compactification is more like a circle!

Comment: Building on  what Sambo says:  in the one case, if you remove $0$, you are left with two disjoint open sets and in the other, with one open set.

Comment: So, you've been referring to a set got by adding **two** points to $\Bbb R$ as its **one**-point compactification?

Comment: See [this 13 February 2002 sci.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=367112) and [A question about some  special compactifications of $\mathbb{R}$](https://mathoverflow.net/q/95748/15780).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is this: What you give is actually a **two**-point compactification: it's compact like a line segment.

The **one**-point compactification is compact like a circle.

It has *one* infinite element, $\infty$, which can be reached both by going infinitely far in the positive direction *and* infinitely far in the *negative* direction. Effectively, you can think of it as being ordered like this:

$$0 < 1 < 1000 < \cdots < \infty < -1000 < -1 < 0$$

. It also is the space you need to use if you want the equality

$$\frac{1}{0} = \infty$$

to make sense, with suitable extension of the division operator by continuity.(*) Note that

$$\frac{0}{0}$$

is still undefined, however.

---

(*) This is because the graph of $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ has branches tending to infinity in *both* positive *and* negative directions near $0$.

Comment: Is $(-\infty, \infty)$ considered as the one point compactification?

Comment: @Shamisen Expert : No. That is just $\mathbb{R}$ itself. Note that it is an "open" interval: its "endpoints" are _not_ included.

Comment: The one-point compactification can't really be written as an interval. As a set, it is $\mathbb{R} \cup \{ \infty \}$. Then you have to make the right definitions for topological and order structure (technically, order has to become a ternary, not binary, relation to avoid becoming trivial).

Comment: Sorry, I meant $(-\infty, \infty]$. Ok, so $\mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$ with additional structure.